# How to select from MySQL JSON array as rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, unnest

Using MySQL 5.7, how can I select array elements from a JSON column, as rows?

**Table `Person`**

```
id      data
1       [{"name":"one"},{"name":"two"}]
2       [{"name":"three"},{"name":"four"}]
```

I want to "pivot" the elements in the JSON array to rows. *Non-working* SQL below...

```
SELECT
    p.id AS personId,
    d->'$.name' AS name
FROM
    Person p
    JSON_EXTRACT(p.data) d  # <-- not valid SQL
WHERE
    d->'$.name' <> 'three'
```

**Expected Output**

```
personId  name
1         one
1         two
2         four
```

Comment: The only reasonable way to do this in to use JSON_TABLE() in MySQL 8.0, so you should upgrade. The alternative is to store your data in normal rows and columns. I would recommend avoiding JSON in your case anyway, since you need to search for a specific value in a JSON field. I recommend to reference JSON fields only in the select-list, and no other clause of your query.

Comment: This is an existing DB (not as pictured here). We don't use the JSON data in SQL queries, this is for data recovery purposes where it'd be helpful to narrow our fix based on some value(s) in the JSON blob. Other than that it's not touched by the DB. Yes, upgrading to MySQL 8 would be nice...

Answer (score 3):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `json_table()`:

```
select p.id, x.name
from person p
cross join json_table(
    p.data,
    '$[*]' columns (name varchar(50) path '$.name')
) x
where x.name <> 'three'
```

In earlier versions, one alternative is to use a derived table of numbers to unnest the array:

```
select *
from (
    select p.id, json_unquote(json_extract(p.data, concat('$[', n.num, '].name'))) name
    from person p
    inner join (select 0 num union all select 1 union all select 2) n
        on n.num < json_length(p.data)
) t
where name <> 'three'
```

The `union all` subquery should contain at least as many elements as the maximum number of elements in any JSON array of your table.

Demos on DB Fiddle:

- **[MySQL 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62de72ee90c288f6ed70b5677353fc45)**
- **[MySQL 5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=62de72ee90c288f6ed70b5677353fc45)**

Comment: What if he wants to handle a JSON array with four elements? You have to change the query? Forgive me, but this is not a reasonable solution. Which I guess is the point of showing it.

Comment: @BillKarwin: the idea is to have a table of numbers that has largely enough elements, so there is no need to worry about modifying the query later on. As you are aware, there are relatively easy ways to generate very large numbers table. That said, I do agree with you that the data would be best stored in a normalized structure (why did you delete your answer by the way? I find it is very complementary to mine).

Comment: I realized this question was a duplicate, and voted to close it. I felt it would be bad form to post an answer myself and then vote to close the question, blocking others from answering. But I'll add a comment to the same effect.